# Excel VBA create commandbutton

Tags: excel, vba, button, dynamic

How can I add a commandbutton with code to a dynamically created sheet?

I want to run a subrutine in another module when this button is clicked. It's not part of a userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have created the Sheet you can add a button:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(96.75, 44.25, 95.25, 30.75).Select
```

and assign a macro inside the module:

```
Selection.OnAction = "Macro1"
```